# dispersion in summary.glm()

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I conducted a glm.nb by

```
glm1<-glm.nb(x~factor(group))
```

with group being a categorial and x being a metrical variable. When I try to get the summary of the results, I get slightly different results, depending on if I use `summary()` or `summary.glm`. `summary(glm1)` gives me

```
    ...
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
    (Intercept)       0.1044     0.1519   0.687   0.4921  
    factor(gruppe)2   0.1580     0.2117   0.746   0.4555  
    factor(gruppe)3   0.3531     0.2085   1.693   0.0904 .
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    (Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.7109) family taken to be 1)
```

whereas summary.glm(glm1) gives me

```
    ...
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
    (Intercept)       0.1044     0.1481   0.705   0.4817  
    factor(gruppe)2   0.1580     0.2065   0.765   0.4447  
    factor(gruppe)3   0.3531     0.2033   1.737   0.0835 .
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    (Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.7109) family taken to be 0.9509067)
```

I understand the meaning of the dispersion parameter, but not of the line

`(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.7109) family taken to be 0.9509067)`.

In the handbook it says, it would be the estimated dispersion, but it seems to be a bad estimate, as 0.95 is not close to 0.7109, or is the estimated dispersion something different than the estimated dispersion parameter?
I guess, I have to set the dispersion in the `summary.nb(x, dispersion=)` to something, but I'm not sure, if I have to set the dispersion to 1 (which will yield the same result as `summary()` or if I should insert an estimate of the dispersion parameter, in this case leading to `summary.nb(glm1, dispersion=0.7109)` or something else? Or am I fine with just using the `summary(glm1)`?

Comment: Use summary() as it dispatches to the appropriate S3 method for class negbin. The dispersion must of course be 1, what gets estimated is theta, which is better called a shape parameter to avoid confusion. See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27773/how-does-glm-nb-work/27834#27834

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly, you should not use `summary.glm` on an object of class `"negbin"`. If you look at the function code for `summary.glm`, right at the top you'll see the computation of the `dispersion`. Note that `summary.glm` *only* knows about models that can be fitted by `glm` and hence it singles out the binomial and Poisson families for special treatment, where the dispersion parameter $\phi$ is *assumed* to be equal to 1. For models other than these, $\phi$ is computed from the model object, but note that this is based on an assumption that this is appropriate for a family that is *not* binomial or Poisson. The `family` for the model fitted by `glm.nb` is `"Negative Binomial(theta)"`. Hence when you use `summary.glm` on the model fitted by `glm.nb`, the in code

```
if (is.null(dispersion)) 
    dispersion <- if (object$family$family %in% c("poisson", 
        "binomial")) 
        1
    else if (df.r > 0) {
        est.disp <- TRUE
        if (any(object$weights == 0)) 
                warning("observations with zero weight not used for calculating dispersion")
            sum((object$weights * object$residuals^2)[object$weights > 
            0])/df.r
    }
```

the test for `"poisson"` or `"binomial"` fails and it then computes $\phi$ where in actual fact it is assumed to be equal to 1 by default for this family (as per the definition of `summary.negbin`.

There is no problem with this, it is just simpler to call the correct method and supply a different value for $\phi$ via argument `dispersion`.

Secondly, you misunderstand the output. When you see

```
Negative Binomial(0.7109)
```

as I alluded to above, the number quoted in parentheses is $\hat{\theta}$, the parameter of the Negative Binomial distribution. This value is that estimated during fitting. It is not $\phi$, the dispersion parameter, and hence the two numbers should not necessarily be equal; they are just two numbers.

As the computed dispersion $\phi$ (following the code I quote above) is pretty close to one (~0.95), the assumption that $\phi = 1$ used for the standard errors is not too bad in `summary.negbin`. You could of course, just do

```
summary(glm1, dispersion = 0.9509)
```

and get the additional output that the `negbin` method gives you, *plus* the computed rather than assumed value of $\phi$.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation. I have two small comments: The dispersion parameter in binomial, Poisson and negative binomial with known shape parameter is 1 by definition of the exponential family (it's not an assumption). When you say that a different dispersion can be estimated and supplied to the summary method then one must be careful because one would venture into quasi territory which has implications especially for the likelihood.

Comment: @Momo Well said. I was torn between what you state and the details of the help page for the respective functions.

Answer (score 2):

From Venables & Ripley (2002), *Modern Applied Statistics with S*: 'Theta' defines a gamma distribution with shape $\theta$ & scale $\frac{1}{\theta}$, hence mean $1$ & variance $\frac{1}{\theta}$. Let $E$ be a random variable with this distribution; a response $Y$ is distributed conditionally on $E$ as Poisson with mean $\mu E$, where $\mu$ is a function of the predictors & coefficients depending on your choice of link. Marginally, its distribution is negative binomial, with mass function

$$
f(y)=\frac{\Gamma(\theta +y)}{\Gamma(\theta) y!}\cdot\frac{\mu^y \theta^\theta}{(\mu+\theta)^{\theta+y}}
$$

expectation

$$\operatorname{E}Y=\mu$$

& variance

$$\operatorname{Var} Y = \mu +\frac{\mu^2}{\theta}$$

As @Momo points out, the dispersion parameter is another thing entirely, which you'd let vary to do quasi-likelihood estimation. For the negative binomial model & the (true) Poisson model, it's rightly fixed to a value of one.