# Negative Binomial "Process"

Tags: r, regression, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I wish to model the number of bugs caused by software development. This is intuitively sort of a Poisson process, however it is overdispersed. One thing we can do in this case is to use a negative binomial distribution (because negative binomial approaches Poisson as `r` gets larger, or because we might think the parameter $\lambda$ of the poisson is itself gamma-distributed.)

I'm not sure how to do this though. For example, we have that 
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}NB\left(r,\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+r}\right)=\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$$
Given that a poisson process of duration $t$ can be modeled as $\text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ I guess we could look at $NB\left(r,\frac{\lambda t}{\lambda t+r}\right)$ - is that correct? Given that I know $t$, it seems like I should be setting $r=t$.

At a more technical level, `glm.nb` from the `MASS` package seems to fit $r$ not the dispersion parameter and I don't see an obvious parameter to change this.

Any insight at the theoretical or technical level would be appreciated.

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70619/dispersion-in-summary-glm/77594#77594) for what `glm.nb` is doing (taken from the book).

Answer (score 14):

Several stochastic processes lead to marginal counts having a Negative
Binomial (NB) distribution and can therefore be called *NB processes*.
Among them, the *NB Lévy Process* is of special interest since
increments (counts) over non-overlapping time intervals are
independent, a property shared with the Poisson Process, a Gamma
process and the Wiener Process.  The count $N_t$ on an interval of
length $t$ has the NB distribution
$$
   N_t \sim \textrm{NB}(r,\,p), \quad r = \gamma t
$$ 
so the process depends on the two parameters $\gamma >0$ (with the
dimension of an inverse time) and the probability $p$  ($0 < p < 1$).
The expectation is proportional to the interval length, and so is its
variance
$$
  \mathbb{E}(N_t) = \gamma t \, (1-p)/p \qquad 
  \textrm{Var}(N_t) =  \gamma t \, (1-p)/p^2.
$$ 
The variance is greater than the mean (overdispersion), and the
index of dispersion $\textrm{Var}(N_t)/\mathbb{E}(N_t) = 1/p$ does not
depend on $t$.  When $p$ is close to $1$ and $\gamma (1-p)$ 
is close to $\lambda >0$, the process behaves like 
a Poisson Process with rate $\lambda$.
An explanation for overdispersion is that several events can happen at
the same time, so a small interval can contain more than one event.

It is easy to fit such a process by Maximum Likelihood when the
intervals have different lengths.  In this case we face a NB regression
with a link function differing from the default link in NB GLMs. A 
special likelihood maximisation is useful.

The [article by T.J. Kozubowski and K. Podgorski](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~pms/files/29.1/Article/29.1.3.pdf) provide theoretical
results as well as an illustration.

Curiously enough, this process does not seem to be frequently used 
as such by statisticians.

Comment: Can you say what you mean by: "A special likelihood maximisation is useful."?

Comment: For a given value of $\gamma$, the value $\widehat{p}(\gamma)$ of $p$ maximising the log-likelihood $\log L(\gamma, p)$ can be given in closed form. Thus we can maximise the *concentrated* (or *profile*) log-likelihood $\log L[\gamma, \widehat{p}(\gamma)]$, a function of the single parameter $\gamma$. Moreover the second order derivative of the concentrated log-likelihood can be obtained in closed form and it can proved that the profile log-likelihood is concave, so a global maximum exists.