# negative binomial inter-arrival

Tags: stochastic-processes, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-process, interarrival-time

I am trying to find out what is the distribution governing the inter-arrival of events for a counting process that follows a negative binomial? I know for a Poisson counting process the inter-arrival times follow an exponential distribution, but I can't seem to find the answer for a negative binomial process.

Thank you.

Comment: It's going to depend on how the negative binomial itself is generated.  For example, one way is to say you have a Gamma distribution on the Poisson parameter; another is to say you have a Poisson distribution for the occurrence of "events", and when an event occurs, you have a logarithmic distribution for the associated count; the distribution of the number of counts is negative binomial, but the interarrival times are a mixture of a discrete mass at zero and an exponential distribution.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77762/negative-binomial-process

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the comments. But, the NB is a fit to a dataset I have done on event occurrence. I would like to know simulate and get some simulated event occurrences. What distribution should I use to get those arrival times?

Comment: Knowing that the number of events over some fixed period of time $\sim$ Negative Binomial isn't enough to tell you the interarrival time distribution, because there are different interarrival time distributions that can result in exactly the same Negative Binomial distribution for the # of events over a fixed time interval.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is getting more clear to me now. So knowing that its a NB, you say there is potentially a range of interarrival time distributions I can use. Could you point me to one that is easy to use and what would be the parameters of that distribution given that we know the NB parameters? Thanks.

Comment: @davidmoutarde I have similar problem, did you find manage to simulate inter arrival time for negative binomial distribution, thx